# Stop an increasing infinite recursive template instantiation, that is not needed

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation

I'm implementing a graph class, with each vertex having a Label of not necessarily the same type. I want the user to be able to provide any Labels (at compile time), without the Graph or the Vertex to know what the type is. For this, I used templated polymorphism, which I've hidden inside a Label class, in order for the Labels to have value semantics. It works like a charm and the relevant code is this (ignore the commented parts for now):

```cpp
//Label.hpp:
#include <memory>

class Label {
public:
    template<class T> Label(const T& name) : m_pName(new Name<T>(name)) {}
    Label(const Label& other) : m_pName(other.m_pName->copy()) {}
//  Label(const Label& other, size_t extraInfo) : m_pName(other.m_pName->copyAndAddInfo(extraInfo)) {}
    bool operator==(const Label& other) const { return *m_pName == *other.m_pName; }
private:
    struct NameBase {
    public:
        virtual ~NameBase() = default;
        virtual NameBase* copy() const = 0;
//      virtual NameBase* copyAndAddInfo(size_t info) const = 0;
        virtual bool operator==(const NameBase&  other) const = 0;
    };

    template<class T> struct Name : NameBase {
    public:
        Name(T name) : m_name(std::move(name)) {}
        NameBase* copy() const override { return new Name<T>(m_name); }
//      NameBase* copyAndAddInfo(size_t info) const override {
//          return new Name<std::pair<T, size_t>>(std::make_pair(m_name, info));
//      }
        bool operator==(const NameBase& other) const override {
            const auto pOtherCasted = dynamic_cast<const Name<T>*>(&other);
            if(pOtherCasted == nullptr) return false;
            return m_name == pOtherCasted->m_name;
        }
    private:
        T m_name;
    };

    std::unique_ptr<NameBase> m_pName;
};
```

One requirement of the user (aka me) is to be able to create disjoint unions of Graphs (he is already able to create dual Graphs, unions of Graphs (where vertices having the same Label, are mapped to the same vertex), etc.). The wish is that the labels of the new Graph are pairs of the old label and some integer, denoting from which graph the label came (this also ensures that the new labels are all different). For this, I thought that I could use the commented parts of the Label class, but the problem that my g++17 compiler has, is that the moment I define the first Label with some type T, it tries to instantiate everything that could be used:

```cpp
Name<T>, Name<std::pair<T, size_t>>, Name<std::pair<std::pair<T, size_t>, size_t>>, ...
```

Try for example to compile this (just an example, that otherwise works):

```cpp
// testLabel.cpp:
#include "Label.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<Label> labels;
    labels.emplace_back(5);
    labels.emplace_back(2.1);
    labels.emplace_back(std::make_pair(true, 2));
    Label testLabel(std::make_pair(true, 2));
    for(const auto& label : labels)
        std::cout<<(label == testLabel)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The compilation just freezes. (I do not get the message "maximum template recursion capacity exceeded", that I saw others get, but it obviously tries to instantiate everything). I've tried to separate the function in another class and explicitly initialize only the needed templates, in order to trick the compiler, but with no effect.

The desired behaviour (I do not know if possible), is to instantiate the used template classes (together with the member function declarations), but define the member functions lazily, i.e. only if they really get called. For example, if I call `Label(3)`, there should be a class `Name<int>`, but the function

```cpp
NameBase* Name<int>::copyAndAddInfo(size_t info) const;
```

shall only be defined if I call it, at some point. (thus, the `Name<std::pair<int, size_t>>` is only going to be instantiated on demand)

It feels like something which should be doable, since the compiler already defines templated functions on demand.

An idea whould be to completely change the implementation and use variants, but

1. I do not want to keep track of the types the user needs manually, and
2. I quite like this implementation approach and want to see its limits, before changing it.

Does anyone have any hints on how I could solve this problem?

Comment: Do you want to be able to repeat this construction? As in, do you want to be able to have `Name<std::pair<std::pair<T, size_t>, size_t>`. If not, you could add a partial specification of `Name` for `std::pair<T, size_t>` (or preferably an own type, otherwise, one had unexpected behavior, if one wanted to label with a pair).

Comment: Yes, in theory I want to be able to take arbitrarily many disjoint unions (not that I really am going to). But, I think that may work either wise (with a custom struct of course, not a pair). Maybe the compiler is going to choose to use the general templated class, as long as the user calls the respective copyAndAddInfo() function and fall back in the specialization when the function is not used any more. I will try that out and let you know. Thanks :)

Comment: I don't think what you want to do is possible. If you have `Name<T>` anywhere, the compiler will create the code for `Name<std::pair<T, size_t>>`, since it has to create the `copyAndAddInfo` method that needs this type. But then, it has to create the next recursion and so on. Specifically, the depth of this is not known at compile time. Consider for example the following code: `std::unique_ptr<NodeBase> ptr; for(auto i = 0; i < n; ++i) { ptr = ptr->copyAndAddInfo();}`, where `n` is some runtime input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer your question, the virtual and template combo makes it impossible for the compiler to lazily implement the body `copyAndAddInfo`. The virtual base type pointer hides the type information, so when the compiler sees `other.m_pName->copyAndAddInfo`, it couldn't know what type it needs to lazily implement.

EDIT:

Ok, so based on your rationale for using templates, it seems like you only want to accept labels of different types, and might not actually care if the disjoint union information is part of the type. If that's the case, you could move it from the name to the label, and make it run-time information:

```cpp
class Label {
public:
    template<class T> Label(const T& name) : m_pName(new Name<T>(name)) {}
    Label(const Label& other) : m_pName(other.m_pName->copy()), m_extraInfo(other.m_extraInfo) { }
    Label(const Label& other, size_t extraInfo) : m_pName(other.m_pName->copy()), m_extraInfo(other.m_extraInfo) {
        m_extraInfo.push_back(extraInfo);
    }
    bool operator==(const Label& other) const { 
        return *m_pName == *other.m_pName && std::equal(
            m_extraInfo.begin(), m_extraInfo.end(), 
            other.m_extraInfo.begin(), other.m_extraInfo.end()); }
private:
    struct NameBase { /* same as before */ };

    std::vector<size_t> m_extraInfo;
    std::unique_ptr<NameBase> m_pName;
};
```

If the disjoint union info being part of the type *is* important, than please enjoy my original sarcastic answer below.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

That said, if you're willing to put a cap on the recursion, I have an evil solution for you that works for up to N levels of nesting: use template tricks to count the level of nesting. Then use SFINAE to throw an error after N levels, instead of recursing forever.

First, to count the levels of nesting:

```cpp
template <typename T, size_t Level>
struct CountNestedPairsImpl
{
    static constexpr size_t value = Level;
};

template <typename T, size_t Level>
struct CountNestedPairsImpl<std::pair<T, size_t>, Level> : CountNestedPairsImpl<T, Level + 1>
{
    using CountNestedPairsImpl<T, Level + 1>::value;
};

template <typename T>
using CountNestedPairs = CountNestedPairsImpl<T, 0>;
```

Then, use `std::enable_if<>` to generate different bodies based on the nesting level:

```cpp
constexpr size_t NESTING_LIMIT = 4;
NameBase* copyAndAddInfo(size_t info) const override {
    return copyAndAddInfoImpl(info);
}
template <typename U = T, typename std::enable_if<CountNestedPairs<U>::value < NESTING_LIMIT, nullptr_t>::type = nullptr>
NameBase* copyAndAddInfoImpl(size_t info) const {
    return new Name<std::pair<T, size_t>>(std::make_pair(m_name, info));
}
template <typename U = T, typename std::enable_if<CountNestedPairs<U>::value >= NESTING_LIMIT, nullptr_t>::type = nullptr>
NameBase* copyAndAddInfoImpl(size_t info) const {
    throw std::runtime_error("too much disjoint union nesting");
}
```

Why did I call this evil? It's going to generate every possible level of nesting allowed, so if you use `NESTING_LIMIT=20` it will generate 20 classes per label type. But hey, at least it compiles!

https://godbolt.org/z/eaQTzB

Comment: First of all, the edited solution solves fully this particular problem. The few extra functions that I have in the Label class, like hashing and printing labels can very easily be modified to account for this extra member. Now it seems like an obvious fix, I never considered. Thank you very much. :)

Having said that, I think that your original answer may in fact be more useful (no matter how evil), since I wanted to experiment with sfinae for a long time, but I did not have an example of my own to do this, so thank you a lot about this as well.

Comment: Thanks for kind words @D.Bogiokas . I made a minor correction though: the counting trick is using [partial specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization), rather than SFINAE. The SFINAE bit is using `enable_if` to add compile-time conditions to `copyAndAddInfoImpl`.